# In Windows how to get highlighted text in a window that belongs to another process using C++ or C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

It's in a C++ translation program. When user selects some text in some other program without pressing CTRL-C, I want to get the highlighted text so that I could translate it. C# solutions are welcome because this(text acquisition) is a relatively standalone component.

One possible solution is to add hook to mouse event. I detect the following messages: mouse drag with left button hold, then release left button. Then I send CTRL-C to the program and get the text from clipboard.

I save and restore clipboard so most programs would work well with the method. But I have observed some programs would process events like WM_KEYUP in their message loops. For these programs I send fake messages! Is there another safer way to get the highlighted text?

I was trying to find some API call to get text between two mouse cursor positions, but I cannot find one.

Comment: You ought to look into UI Automation - the facilities that e.g. screen readers and other accessibility tools use. Specifics depend on what language/libraries you're working with.

Comment: You need to add a language tag, so we know what types of information would be useful. How you do this would depend in part on the language you're using, the functionality it already has, and what can be done using it.  (Not having one means you could get an answer in C++, when you're looking for one in Python; the person answering for C++ has just wasted their time and effort.) Please [edit] to do so; a vague 'windows' tag isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to write a Windows program that interacts with another programs GUI interface is to use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Specifically, you'll write a [UI Automation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It requires a bit of work, but a UI Automation solution will work with almost every other application.  A hacky solution built on hooks and messages will also be a lot of work, but it will be very fragile.  It will only work with certain kinds of applications in certain contexts.  Lots of things can go wrong.

Comment: Thanks. After skimming through the content, it seems like what I want.